# SQL Finding Records Containing Same Character 1 or More Times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I did not find anything in my search. Also, if anyone has a better suggestion for a title, feel free to edit my post.

What I am trying to do is find records that look like this:

1. Xxxxxxx
2. Aaaaaaaa
3. aaaaaaaa
4. bBbbbbbbb

I do NOT want to return records that look like this

1. abcdef
2. 123 abc
3. 123 aaaaaa

Is there anyway to do this?

**Edit #1:**

Basically, I want to find records where the column contains only 1 character, regardless of the case, repeated multiple times.

Comment: So, to confirm in a more simplistic answer, you want rows where the value is made up of a single character, regardless of case? Your title says "Continainer same character 1 or more times", but '123 aaaaaa'` contains many a's, so not sure why that wouldn't meet the requirement.

Comment: Correct, single character 1 or more times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want strings that are all the same character, one method uses `replace()`:

```
where len(replace(upper(col), upper(left(col, 1)), '')) = 0
```

`upper()` is not needed for case-insensitive collations.

You can also use `replicate()`:

```
where upper(col) = replicate(left(upper(col), 1), len(col))
```

Comment: One caveat is this will return strings like 'aa  aa' where this is only a single character but also spaces.

Comment: But @SeanLange is correct: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b050f9962fc2b54091f2ff713a23b98)

Comment: Your replicate method, however, does not suffer this problem ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8f114a1f5be7c4770ca009856a99800))

Comment: @SeanLange . . . My apologies.  Trailing spaces are removed when comparing strings.  Duh!  I replaced it with `len()` instead of a string comparison.

Comment: You'll want `DATALENGTH`, Gordon. `LEN` ignores trailing spaces too. If you try `SELECT LEN(''), LEN(' ');` you'll see that both expressions return `0`, where as if you use `DATALENGTH` (SELECT DATALENGTH(''), DATALENGTH(' ');) it'll return `0` and `1` respectively. [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=82924cd668cfb0c3e6f33131a064d973)

Comment: Currently playing around with this solution. Side note: I had no idea there was a function called replicate, so that will definitely be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

One idea, using [`NGrams8k`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) is to check the maximum and minimum characters are the same:

```
SELECT V.String
FROM (VALUES(1,'Xxxxxxx'),
            (2,'Aaaaaaaa'),
            (3,'aaaaaaaa'),
            (4,'bBbbbbbbb'),
            (5,'abcdef'),
            (6,'123 abc'),
            (7,'123 aaaaaa'))V(ID,String)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(V.String,1) NG
GROUP BY V.ID,
         V.String
HAVING MAX(UPPER(NG.token)) = MIN(UPPER(NG.token));
```

Comment: Thanks for the plug!

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t VALUES ('a'),('b'),
('Xxxxxxx'),('Aaaaaaaa'),('aaaaaaaa'),('bBbbbbbbb'),('abcdef'),('123 abc'),('123 aaaaaa');

-- Solution
SELECT t.string
FROM  @t AS t
WHERE LEN(t.string) > 1 
AND   PATINDEX('%[^'+LEFT(t.string,1)+']%', SUBSTRING(t.string,2,8000)) = 0;
```

**Results:**

```
string
-------------------
Xxxxxxx
Aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
bBbbbbbbb
```